# Spark Maven fail to find ml classes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pom.xml

I create code spark with SparkSession but  i can't run this code.
I think I am missing some dependencies in my pom.xml or something else-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("loader")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
```

**pom.xml for scala 2.11**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>info.daviot</groupId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <scala.version>2.11.5</scala.version>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- optional dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.softwaremill.macwire</groupId>
            <artifactId>macros_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
            <artifactId>akka-actor_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.nscala-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>nscala-time_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.propensive</groupId>
            <artifactId>rapture-json-jawn_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- logs -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.clapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzled-slf4j_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I got the same  **error** when I tried to add :

```
  <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>cloudera</id>
                <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/clouderarepos/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>



    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0-cloudera1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
```

**import works :**

- import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
- import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
- import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel

**import dosn't work :**

- import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel
- import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover

**with error Cannot resolve symbol**

Comment: You should probably show the actual code that throws the error, along with a full error message.

Comment: **import works :**

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Tokenizer
import org.apache.spark.ml.Pipeline
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2VecModel

 **import dosn't work :**

import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizerModel
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StopWordsRemover
with error Cannot resolve symbol

Comment: @Aladin add this as en edit to your original question with proper formating

Comment: Alright @MichailN :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you would need these dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

for more information checkout https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark

Answer (score 3):

Add below dependency-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```